# imshow() displays a white image for a grey image

Tags: matlab, imageview, imshow

I have computed an image with values between 0 and 255. When I use imageview(), the image is correctly displayed, in grey levels, but when I want to save this image or display it with imshow, I have a white image, or sometimes some black pixels here and there:

[image: image with imshow(), it appears the same when I save]

Whereas with imageview():

[image]

Can some one help me?

Comment: i don't work with matlab but i have faced such problem once. Try to use `imshow(uint8(image));`

Comment: My saviour! It works! Thank you

Comment: @skm how do I accept? :)

Comment: you have already accepted another answer...may be, juts "vote up" my answer by clicking the "up arrow" for my answer (not comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab expects images of type `double` to be in the 0..1 range and images that are `uint8` in the 0..255 range. You can convert the range yourself (but change values in the process), do an explicit cast (and potentially loose precision) or instruct Matlab to use the minimum and maximum value found in the image matrix as the white and black value to scale to when visualising.

See the following example with an `uint8` image present in Matlab:

```
im = imread('moon.tif');
figure; imshow(im);
figure; imshow(double(im));
figure; imshow(double(im), []);
figure; imshow(im2double(im));
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that you should use `imshow(uint8(image));` on the image before displaying it.